# Find players that played both games

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I want to get the playerid of those who played both chess and checkers.
I have a table that's like this:

```
playerid   game         website
a1         chess        www.abc.com
a2         checkers     www.cba.com
a1         checkers     www.abc.com
b2         chess        www.abc.com
b1         chess        www.abc.com
a3         checkers     www.aaa.com
b2         checkers     www.abc.com
```

Desired output (a3 and b1 should be excluded)

```
a1
b2
```

```
select game, playerid, website
from player_db
where (game= 'chess' or game= 'checkers') and website='abc.com'
group by playerid ;
```

This is my SQL, but it doesn't seem to be getting both of the games -- it selects either chess or checkers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem when using `OR` is that also every entry will be found that satisfies only one of your two conditions, but you want to get only those which meet both conditions. The problem when using `AND` (this answer seems to have been deleted again) will be you will get no rows since a game can't equal "chess" and "checker" the same time.
So, this means you will need two queries and to check which players occur in both of them, one checking for game = "chess" and one for game="checker". There are different options to do this. One possibility is to use an `IN` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT playerid
FROM daily_player
WHERE playerid IN (SELECT playerid FROM daily_player WHERE game = 'chess')
AND playerid IN (SELECT playerid FROM daily_player WHERE game = 'checkers')
AND website='abc.com';
```

Another way is using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT playerid
FROM daily_player d1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM daily_player WHERE game = 'chess' AND playerid = d1.playerid)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM daily_player WHERE game = 'checkers' AND playerid = d1.playerid) 
AND website='abc.com'
```

Please note that your desired outcome of "a1 b2" can only be achieved when using `DISTINCT` and not selecting differing columns like game etc.
In case you want to still select them you can of course do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT playerid,game,website
FROM daily_player
WHERE playerid IN (SELECT playerid FROM daily_player WHERE game = 'chess')
AND playerid IN (SELECT playerid FROM daily_player WHERE game = 'checkers')
AND website='abc.com';
```

But then you will not get the result you have shown, but in this case four lines instead of 2. If you remove the game of the select above, you will get two rows again because the website does not differ.

Answer (score 1):

A little long query with multiple sub queries may do.

```
SELECT playerid FROM daily_player a
WHERE 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM daily_player WHERE game ='chess' AND playerid=a.`playerid`)=1 
AND
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM daily_player WHERE game ='checkers' AND playerid=a.`playerid`)=1
AND website='www.abc.com'
GROUP BY playerid;
```

**RESULT**

```
playerid  
----------
a1        
b2
```

#### Explanation:

1. **1st Subquery** : Evaluate if the player played the game chess.
2. **2nd Subquery** : Evaluate if the player played the game checkers.
3. Check if both subqueries are `TRUE` by using `AND`.
4. Add another `AND` to evaluate the website.

**Note :** If every player can play a single game multiple times you can replace the `=1` with `>=1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select DISTINCT t1.player_id from daily_player as t1
        where exists (select 1 from daily_player as t2 where t1.player_id = t2.player_id and game = 'chess')
        and exists (select 1 from daily_player as t3 where t1.player_id = t3.player_id and game = 'checkers')
        and  website='abc.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually find duplicates in a column by **"HAVING "**.

if you have just two games this is shortest way.

```
SELECT playerid
FROM daily_player
GROUP BY playerid 
HAVING COUNT(playerid ) > 1;
```

Comment: A query like this will not be executed, do you find out why?

Comment: I edited it somehow hope now we have desired answer. And I will be really happy if you tell me my mistake

Comment: Thank you for editing. The problem was that you used * instead of playerid, but you did not group by the other columns. Columns you want to select must appear in the group by clause or you have to execute an aggregate  function on them like SUM() or AVG().

Comment: This will go wrong if the player plays 1 game multiple times and did not play other game, for example the player plays chess 2x and did not play checkers. But it will be a good answer if every player can only play once per game.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Could go for a join function if you don't want a really long query. Something like:

```
create table chess as select * from daily_player where game = 'chess';
create table checkers as select * from daily_player where game = 'checkers';

select chess.playerid from chess inner join checkers
on chess.playerid = checkers.playerid;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch playerid with who played both chess and checkers, then the query will be:

```
SELECT playerid
FROM daily_player
WHERE game in ('checkers', 'chess') && website = 'www.abc.com' GROUP by playerid HAVING COUNT(*)=2;
```